# opendir function corrupts directory name

Tags: c, opendir

I am having a problem with the `opendir` function in C. Here is the code:

Declaration of `rvm`:

```
rvm_t func()
{
   rvmBlock=(rvm_t)malloc(sizeof(rvm_t));
   return rvmBlock;
}

rvm_t rvm;
rvm=func();

printf("rvm->backingStore=%s\n", rvm->backingStore); 
if( (dir = opendir(rvm->backingStore)) !=NULL )
{
   printf("rvm->backingStore inside if=%s\n", rvm->backingStore);
}
```

The output i am getting for this is:

```
rvm->backingStore=rvm_segments/
rvm->backingStore inside if=rvm_segments!?
```

`"!?"` are some garbage characters that are appearing for some reason.

Can someone explain what is going wrong.

Here is the rvm structure:

```
struct rvm_info
{

   char backingStore[20];
   struct memSeg * memSegs[20];
   long int storage_size;
   int memSeg_count;
   FILE * log_fd;
};

typedef struct rvm_info* rvm_t;
```

Comment: Show the declaration of `rvm`, it's probably pointing to an invalid location. I hope you didn't do `rvm_t rvm;` without allocating memory for it, since `rvm_t` is of type `rvm_info*`.

Comment: That's not the declaration of `rvm`, show us where you have something like: `rvm_t rvm ...`.

Comment: @AusCBloke I have added it just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
rvm_t func()
{
   rvmBlock=(rvm_t)malloc(sizeof(rvm_t));
   return rvmBlock;
}
```

`rvm_t` is defined as a pointer to a `struct rvm_info`, therefore you're passing an incorrect size to `malloc`. `sizeof(rvm_t)` equates to the size of a pointer (usually 4 or 8 bytes) and NOT the size of a `struct rvm_info` (which is well over 4 or 8 bytes). You want the size to be that of `struct rvm_info`, NOT a pointer. Change that call to:

```
rvmBlock = malloc( sizeof(*rvmBlock) );
```

Which just means:

```
rvmBlock = malloc( sizeof(struct rvm_info) );
```

Otherwise, you're causing undefined behaviour since you haven't allocated enough memory for a whole `struct rvm_info`. Therefore you'll be storing that string in a part of memory that hasn't been allocated for `rvm`, and any other part of the program could allocate that memory.

It just so happens that a call to `opendir` cause some memory on the heap to be modified, it doesn't directly/on purpose modify the string passed to it, especially since the argument is of type `const char*`.

**EDIT:** As Keith mentioned in the comments, when using C (*not* C++) it can be considered bad to cast the result of `malloc`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) has discussion on the topic.

Comment: Don't cast the result of calling `malloc()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That wasn't intentional, I copy+paste'd his code to show the main error, but I'll edit it anyway since this is purely C and it's not a good habbit.